# Console shows me a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, widget, expression

Working with my angular project, i`ve added a filter of date range (with a from date and to date) in a widget, when my system starts the filters must to have the first day of current month and the current date, it is working but the console shows me the following message.

**ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'fromDate: undefined'. Current value: 'fromDate: Mon Jun 01 2020 21:17:17 GMT-0400 (hora estándar de Chile)'.**

The line in my template of component is the following:

```
 <div class="range-date"  *ngIf = "item?.id === this.widgetEnum.process">
                    <app-range-date [enableInitDate]="true" [(fromDate)]="item.fromDate" [(toDate)]="item.toDate" (dateChange)="changeDateProcess(item)"></app-range-date>
                  </div>
```

please can you give me so kind of the idea regarding with it?

Comment: can you share related code in ts?

Answer (score 0):

You have two way binding on toDate and fromDate. This is fine, but you also have an input (dateChange) which I assume will also affect the toDate and fromDate variables in the component (not sure without component class code). You can only do one or the other. remove either (dateChange) or make it a one way binding

```
<div class="range-date"  *ngIf = "item?.id === this.widgetEnum.process">
                <app-range-date [enableInitDate]="true" [(fromDate)]="item.fromDate" [(toDate)]="item.toDate"></app-range-date>
              </div>
```

OR

```
<div class="range-date"  *ngIf = "item?.id === this.widgetEnum.process">
                <app-range-date [enableInitDate]="true" [fromDate]="item.fromDate" [toDate]="item.toDate" (dateChange)="changeDateProcess(item)"></app-range-date>
              </div>
```